# Using Java-generated UUID with Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, kotlin, uuid

I understand that you can have [Hibernate auto generate ids for you](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers).

But when writing Kotlin it seems much cleaner to generate them in the code itself. That way you don't need a place holder value and the id can be a not-null value:

```
    @Id
    val id: String = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
```

I'm wondering, though, is there anything wrong with this that I'm not thinking of? Seems like if it's a UUID it's a UUID so who cares if it's generated by the application or Hibernate itself.

Comment: I am not sure, but when deserializing, the id could already be set, which might be a problem if you want to create a new entry in your database and the ID is already assigned.

Comment: One thing that comes to my mind is that hibernate would use id from db during fetching and generated id from constructor would be ignored, but generated anyway (wasting cpu and memory to generate it).
You can still have non null field in such a case with `lateinit var` on the field

Comment: Also you should be able to do
`id: UUID = UUID.randomUUID()` without Stringly typed field

Comment: @krzychek So hibernate creates the object then sets its values from the result set with reflection? I was thinking it would set the values from the result set using the constructor, but I suppose not. Anyway, that's such a minor performance consideration I'll probably just go with this, which I think reads more cleanly.

Comment: As far as I know, Kotlin-jpa plugin generates synthetic default constructor for classes annotated with hibernate/jpa annotations. And Hibernate should use this default constructor and set properties via reflection just like it does in clean java.